# When is it appropriate to buy gunships as BIOS?

Tags: allegiance

BIOS have a long research period (10 minutes per item). This means that if they do not get gunships, they may have a hard time even surviving for the time that it takes to get a tech base and real tech up. However, getting a gunship will delay real tech even further while only covering you and your mining for circa 20 minutes (the time for the enemy team to get adv tech online).

What are factions matchups or situations that make buying gunships as BIOS a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the commander is interested in rushing garrison tech, and delaying a techbase, gunships are a necessary evil. However, by not dumping all the starting money into garrison tech and instead rushing a techbase, you can get light tech up around 5 minutes, and mk2 tech at 15 very easily. It is also possible to have bios shipyard up at approximately 9 minutes under medium/high money settings.

against factions with light bases, or rely upon early bombrushing, gunships provide a large advantage

Answer (score 2):

old school answer is when going tac.

Answer (score 1):

Teams with smaller numbers will also fare a little beeter with gunships. A GS can effectively control 2-3 attackers, more with nans and veteran turreters. Large teams will own gunships, especially with enh-adv tech.

Comment: Yeah, gunships are cheese on small teams.